# how to create an automated fluid grid with equal gutters / box-widths?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm having some trouble at wording this, which is probably the main reason as to why I'm not finding any answers.

I have a container, holding multiple (exact count unknown) elements, and I want to display them in a nice and flexible grid. My only requirements are that the size of the boxes is equal on all rows, and the margin between the boxes are too. And of course for them to use the entire width of the column.

Lets say I have 5 boxes, and room to display 3 in a row, I want 3 boxes in the first row, and 2 in the second.

Check this out for some extra visual aid: https://codepen.io/pjetr/pen/vJgzPJ

**display flex, flex-start**

```
|########  ########  ########         |
|########  ########                   |
```

**display flex, flex 1**

```
|###########  ###########  ###########|
|#################  ##################|
```

**display flex, space-between**

```
|########       ########      ########|
|########                     ########|
```

**display flex, space-around**

```
|########      ########       ########|
|       ########        ########      |
```

**option 1: equal gutter**

```
|########       ########      ########|
|########       ########              |
```

**option 2: equal width**

```
|###########  ###########  ###########|
|###########  ###########             |
```

As you can see, there are 2 possible outcomes which I will settle for, but I don't know how to achieve them without javascript.
Is it possible to achieve either with only CSS?

For now I've settled for flex-start, but I hope someone could help me solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
* {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 15px 0 0 15px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
    height: 32px;
    flex: 0 0 calc(calc(100%/3) - 15px);
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: #D0D0D0;
}
```

Comment: I think you could simplify `calc(calc(100%/3) - 15px)` to just `calc((100%/3) - 15px)` but besides that, it's great! Thank you!

Comment: I more of a LessCSS fan, and in Less it doesn't matter if you write the "calc" before the parenthesis. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This is great, combined with media queries I'll even be able to make it even more fluid. I prefer Sass over Less personally :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just don't use a fixed width on your `.box` elements.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 15px 0 0 15px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  height: 32px;
  width: calc((100% / 3) - 15px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: #D0D0D0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not do it totally flexbox way: 

`.box {  ... flex: 0 0 (calc(100%/3) - 15px); ...}`

Comment: Thanks for your comment @AjayGupta! I'd be great if you could post an alternative answer with your method. I'd probably learn a thing or two :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This combined with media-queries will be my chosen solution. **Well...** I'm going with the solution by @AjayGupta. ^^